# Generating a new Controller action in rails via command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I add a new controller action through the command line so that rails automatically generates a view for the action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [bin/rails generate chapter @ guides.rubyonrails.org](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-generate)

```sh
bin/rails generate controller CreditCards open debit credit close

# Credit card controller with URLs like /credit_cards/debit.
# Controller: app/controllers/credit_cards_controller.rb
# Test:       test/controllers/credit_cards_controller_test.rb
# Views:      app/views/credit_cards/debit.html.erb [...]
# Helper:     app/helpers/credit_cards_helper.rb
```

If you already have a controller, do the same, just skip overwriting other stuff.

From the link:

```
bin/rails generate controller Greetings hello
   create  app/controllers/greetings_controller.rb
    route  get "greetings/hello"
   invoke  erb
   create    app/views/greetings
   create    app/views/greetings/hello.html.erb
   invoke  test_unit
   create    test/controllers/greetings_controller_test.rb
   invoke  helper
   create    app/helpers/greetings_helper.rb
   invoke    test_unit
   create      test/helpers/greetings_helper_test.rb
   invoke  assets
   invoke    scss
   create      app/assets/stylesheets/greetings.css.scss
```

As you can see it generates view for one action.

Comment: not valid in rails 6

$ rails g controller Users invite
returns: The name 'UsersController' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative or use --skip-collision-check or --force to skip this check and run this generator again.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know if it's possible to only create actions for a controller that already exists?